# Issue with Forwarding Email Postfix on Ubuntu Running on Amazon EC2

Tags: linux, ubuntu, email, amazon-ec2, postfix

I'm trying to forward email going to user1@domain.com to user2@gmail.com, I read a bunch of articles and can't seem to get it to work.

I have a local user on the server "userA"

If I have "userA: user2@gmail.com" in the aliases table It forwards the emails but only when I send them from the server. But if I try emailing from another email address like user@hotmail.com it won't forward to user@gmail.com

If I have " userA: userA " in the aliases table it has no problem storing the emails on the server.

Any Advise? should I do this differently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest way to do this is to use the `virtual` map.  Just add a line to /etc/postfix/virtual like this:

```
user1@domain.com user2@gmail.com
```

You may need to add

```
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
```

to your main.cf.

Then just rebuild the virtual map:

```
sudo postmap /etc/postfix/virtual
```

and reload:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/postfix reload
```

Comment: Sorry been battling SMTP I'm going to get back to this asap. I didn't forget your response.